# angularjs ng-model in select

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel, ng-options

im stucked in a dumb problem, but i don't know how to go ahead, so i hope that someone of you can give me a help. 
My problem is that i have a list of element, and i can acces for everyone of them, in which i can load the specific data of the element. In this view i can load the data from the REST backend call, and work all prettly, the problem that i have encountered is when i have to load a list with the select tag, and im working with ng-model and ng option. I want to load in that list the data selected that the element have in this moment, but when i try to put in ng-model the data that i give from the backend, that doesnt work, instead if i initialize the same element out of the service call backend that work and i can see the element selected.  The service is working because i can see every value of the element, and even if i try to take the specific value i can see it if for example i put that in a paragraph. Thanks in advance.

this is where i load the list:

```js
  self.AzionePropostaLista=[
      {  qsAzioneProposta:'SENSIBILIZZAZIONE', value: 'SENSIBILIZZAZIONE'},
      {  qsAzioneProposta:'INIBIZIONE MANUAL ENTRY', value: 'INIBIZIONE MANUAL ENTRY'},
      {  qsAzioneProposta:'INIBIZIONE BANDA', value : 'INIBIZIONE BANDA'},
      {  qsAzioneProposta:'INIBIZIONE COMPLETA', value : 'INIBIZIONE COMPLETA'},
      {  qsAzioneProposta:'REVOCA', value : 'REVOCA'},
      {  qsAzioneProposta:'RINUNCIA', value :'RINUNCIA'},
      {  qsAzioneProposta:'SBLOCCO', value :'SBLOCCO'},
      {  qsAzioneProposta:'COMUNICAZIONE INTERNA', value :'COMUNICAZIONE INTERNA'},
      {  qsAzioneProposta:'AUTOFIN.SOSPETTATO', value : 'AUTOFIN.SOSPETTATO'},
      {  qsAzioneProposta:'VALUTATO SENZA RISCHIO', value :'VALUTATO SENZA RISCHIO'}
    ];
```

This is the data that im retriving from the backend service:

> self.condition: "SENSIBILIZZAZIONE"

```js
  MerchantService.getThisAction({qs_key:$routeParams.qs_key,qs_data_proposta:formatData},function(response){
        if(response.statusCode==0){
          self.action = response.data; 
          self.condition = response.data.qsAzioneProposta; THIS DOESN'T WORK BUT I CAN SEE THAT VALUE
          $log.debug("self.condition is"+self.condition);
          
        }
        else {
          sweetAlert('Error','something missing or you are trying to acces an inexistent merchant', 'error');
          $location.path("/home");
        }
      });


    // self.condition = 'SENSIBILIZZAZIONE' THIS WORK
```

```html
  <div class="input-field col s4">
   <select ng-model="$ctrl.condition"  ng-options="azione.value as azione.qsAzioneProposta for azione in $ctrl.AzionePropostaLista"></select>
<label>Suggested action</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[This is the data that i'm retriving from the backend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8AeD.png)

Comment: please post it in your question and as text, not image

Answer (score 0):

Your `ng-model` aggregates `azione.value` from `ng-options` therefore:

Change:

```
self.condition = response.data.qsAzioneProposta;
```

to:

```
self.condition = response.data.value;
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/yeXRpVqyi8dXDBsPJy8H?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: that's doesn't make sense, because i don't have a field called value in what the back is retriving to me. Just i'm retriving value, but i don't understand why if i take the value from the back doesn't work, if i do the same thing out of the service call writing myself the string, as the self.condition below the code, that work.

Comment: @AntonioPraticò well, in your question you posted code with `ng-options="azione.value as ...`

Comment: `ng-options="azione.qsAzioneProposta as azione.qsAzioneProposta for azione in $ctrl.AzionePropostaLista"` should do

Comment: because i need too the value in ng-options, i've edit the post with the array of the list.

Comment: @AntonioPraticò so where is a problem? http://plnkr.co/edit/slDQkk4EdtZXMBKmrIwj?p=preview

Comment: yes, thats right and you got it,  $scope.condition = items[0].value; OK, but i want initialize with the data that im retriving from the back, whit the same value that the element has now, not with a default value.

Comment: @MaximShoustin thanks for your patience. Ok, but so there is something wrong in my service? but i can see all data so i dont understand where is the mistake.

Comment: @AntonioPraticò I think I gave you enough tips and demos.

Comment: Nothing to do, i've worked with a service which return a string like you did, and work. In my specific case, this kind of service isn't working, but is really strange, because if i inspect my html i can see the element selected, but it isn't showed in the select field view.